# Processing Date in Struts 1 ActionForm

Tags: java, string, date, actionform, struts1

I have problem on processing input request parameter (of course it's type String) to `java.util.Date`. I thought that following code added to my bean might solve this problem, but I was wrong:

```
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setDate(String dateString) {
    try {
        date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        date = new Date();
    }
}
```

It throws an exception after submiting form:

> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
> org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:469)
> org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:818)
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.epam.testapp.model.News.setDate - argument type mismatch
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1778)
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1759)
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1648)
> org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1677)
> ```

Is this fundamental of struts 1 form that this code won't work because of mismatch of returning getter and accepting setter parameter types? How can I solve this problem ? I don't want at all to make method named like `setStringDate(String stringDate(){...}` and think on every page which method should I call :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date object cannot be a property in struts as date format can vary (depending on specification). Some may have `dd-MM-yyyy`, `dd-MMMM-yy`, etc.

I would suggest having a property:

```
private String date;

public String getDate() { return date; }

public void setDate(String date) { this.date = date; }
```

And in your action, convert the date string into `Date` object.

Comment: That's what I've done. Just wanted to sure there is no better solution :) But still interesting question: why invoke() cannot determine right overloaded method. I have no idea why struts developers missed this case.

Comment: That's because Struts has no way to convert an entered date into a respective `Date` object without a conversion pattern.

Comment: Well I'm not asking it to parse Date. I mean I don't understand why there is no dynamic invokation of proper setter method. At request time RequestProcessor has String value for specific request parameter. Why cant it choose more fitting method: set...(Date) or set...(String). I'm not asking to parse Date, I just want to have implemented some natural to me as a Java programmer things :))

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge I think , overloaded methods don't work very well in form beans .Try naming the two methods differently, and I think you'll have better luck.